# this.setState inside navigationOptions gives error _this2.setState is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation` for routing purpose. On one component I am trying to set navigationOptions to show hamburger button to open and close sidebar(drawer). so onPress I am trying to setState for my sidebar flag but it is giving an error `_this2.setState is not a function` People are suggesting `bind` but I don't think it would go with my scenario. 
Here is the code.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
        headerLeft: 
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => { this.setState({ Sidebar: true }); }}
            >
            <Image 
                source={{ uri: 'https://rsna2015.rsna.org/images/hamburger-stale.png' }}
                style={{ height: 35, width: 35, marginLeft: 10 }} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
});
```

Comment: no way to reference this from a static method.

Answer (score 4):

That's it, expected behaviour.

Static method calls are made on the class, not on the instance. There is no way to reference `this` in static method.

Writing post on mechanism to solve this in a clear, declarative way, unfortunately, not ready yet.

"Dirty" (imperative) solution for time being would be...

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
  headerLeft: navigation.state.params ? navigation.state.params.headerLeft : null
});

componentDidMount() {
  // Set route params
  this.navigation.setParams({
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => { this.setState({ Sidebar: true }); }}
      >
        <Image 
          source={{ uri: 'https://rsna2015.rsna.org/images/hamburger-stale.png' }}
          style={{ height: 35, width: 35, marginLeft: 10 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Did not work.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headerLeft' of undefined

Comment: Fair enough, `navigation.state.params` is `undefined` until you explicitly set it using `setParams`. See updated answer. To be honest, little debugging does not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
  headerLeft: navigation.state.params ? navigation.state.params.headerLeft : null
});

componentDidMount() {
  // Set route params
  this.props.navigation.setParams({
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => { this.setState({ Sidebar: true }); }}
      >
        <Image 
          source={{ uri: 'https://rsna2015.rsna.org/images/hamburger-stale.png' }}
          style={{ height: 35, width: 35, marginLeft: 10 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.